# C# Why it is a WRONG output when I write data to a file?

Tags: c#, io

This is my code:

```
{    
FileStream hd = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(hd);
bw.Write("Tien an uong:");
bw.Write(anuong); //double
bw.Write("\n");
bw.Write("Tien hat:");
bw.Write(hat);//double
bw.Write("\n");
bw.Write("Tong cong tien phai thanh toan:");
bw.Write(s);//double
bw.Close();
hd.Close();
}
```

and this is what output file got: 
Tien an uong:     jè@
    Tien hat:     ùA
Tong cong tien phai thanh toan:    @A

I need you help!

Answer (score 4):

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(hd);
```

Binary - not text.

```
bw.Write(hat); //double
```

Happily writes out the bytes of the `double` as bytes - not as text.

I suggest you use a `TextWriter`, instead of a `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: In this case use a `StreamWriter` because `TextWriter` is abstract.

Comment: when using TextWriter, I just wonder if there will be wrong when reading that file?

Comment: Well, not if you program without errors, you know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you're having a problem with the double's, so I assume that a simple `ToString()` will solve your issue, but it seems you just want it as a string, so how about:

```
{    
FileStream hd = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(hd);
bw.Write(string.Format(@"Tien an uong:{0}{1}Tien hat:{2}{1}Tong cong tien phai thanh toan:{3}", anuong, Environment.NewLinew, hat, s);
bw.Close();
hd.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much much! When reading that file, there's no issue, right?

Comment: It depends; If you want to read it as a string (and output it or something) then no.

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding of binary writer is UTF-8 (which is ascii compatible), writing doubles will directly write the doubles as byes to the stream, resulting in unexpected characters.

You should ether use a stream writer with the encoding of your choice
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Or stick to the write function of BinaryWriter that takes a string and will encode in UTF-8. All tough that doesn't seem very logical.